# The default favicon shows up while the page is loading but it switches to my custom favicon after

Tags: 8, theming

I have my custom favicon.ico set up in my themes custom folder and it renders correctly for every page on my site. However, in the process of it rendering, it flashes the default Drupal logo for a split second before showing my custom favicon. I have my Global Settings set to Use the favicon supplied by the theme, then both my Claro and custom theme set to the path of my custom favicon(the favicon used by Global Settings in my themes custom folder). Any ideas on whats causing this?

Comment: Browsers can cache favicons so the first thing to check is whether this happens in an incognito session. Next, is the Drupal logo returned by a request to /favicon.ico? Last is there any occurrence of '/misc/favicon.ico' in the page source?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! It is happening in an incognito session. When you say returned by a request, what do you mean? Cause I thought if I created a custom /favicon.ico file Drupal automatically picks it out and uses it, then ignores any previous default favicon.

Comment: Try visiting the url "http//:mysite.example.com/favicon.ico". Browsers will look at this location for the favicon by default.

Comment: I'm running the site locally via MAMP Pro. If I do add the /favicon.ico anyway it gives me a 404 error

Comment: OK, did you view source in your browser to check the HTML for the page for any mention of "/misc/favicon.ico"?

Comment: Yes, in the (index) I search favicon.ico and there's only one instance of it as an href in a link tag and it is pointing to the correct file (```/themes/custom/mytheme/favicon.ico```). Did a global search too and thats the only favicon.ico file that shows up. The confusion is real.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104331/discussion-between-alfred-armstrong-and-joe-spinelli).

Comment: so ? what is the solution ?